# strange selector behavior in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-selectors

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L3uP7/4/)

The selector highlights all tables rather than the one it should be selecting. It only does this for the first list item. If I move selected="selected" to another list item, I don't have the issue. I don't see this issue in ff for ie.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a new bug?

css

```
  li[selected="selected"] table
  {
    background:yellow;
  }
```

html

```
<li selected="selected">
        <a href="#">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Row 1 - Col 1
                    </td>
                    <td class="second">
                        Row 1 - Col 2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Row 2 - Col 1
                    </td>
                    <td class="second">
                        Row 2 - Col 2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Row 3 - Col 1
                    </td>
                    <td class="second">
                        Row 3 - Col 2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: BTW: using Chome 13.0.782.112 m  on windows

Comment: Just use a class instead of defining custom attributes: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/L3uP7/5/

Comment: I don't see this issue on chrome 13.0.782.112m. However "selected" attribute shouln't be used for <li>.

Comment: Why are you making entire tables links?

Comment: The actual page is much more complicated, from a php site using javascript/ajax. This is just a simplified version.

Comment: I'd have to rewrite a php helper function to change it to class="selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making your selector a little more specific?

EG:  `li[selected="selected"] table td`

Comment: Yes this works. I'll change it to this way. Just wondering if what I did before was wrong?

Comment: Well...I personally wouldn't say "wrong" but as has been stated above it would be better to use a class. But as your using a CMS this may not be an option.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is that `selected` is not a valid attribute for an `<LI>` tag.  Chrome is (right or wrong) simply ignoring that element in your CSS.

If you used `class` instead, then you could select it correctly in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/SReUe/

Comment: The cms I use has a helper function that adds selected="selected". It was usually used in <select>, but I didn't have a problem before moving to <li>

Comment: Yes, the `<option>` element can contain `selected` - that's part of the spec.  Just changing the element doesn't mean all attributes are allowed.